# How many usb devices does raspberry support?

Tags: raspbian, usb-hub

Colleagues, hello, everyone. I have a raspberry that produces errors, 10 usb devices connected to it via hub. What's the diagnosis?

I have the following equipment installed:raspberry pi4 model B 4 GB, hub ORICO P10-U3, modems huawei e3372h 10 pieces. 
All errors - https://dropmefiles.com/cWJL6

````
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.97-v7l+ (dom@buildbot) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611)) #1294 SMP Thu Jan 30 13:21:14 GMT 2020
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd083] revision 3 (ARMv7), cr=30c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, PIPT instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 256 MiB at 0x000000001ec00000
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 1012736
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 1728 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 196608 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000]   HighMem zone: 816128 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0xc0/0x4e8 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 17 pages/cpu s36928 r8192 d24512 u69632
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s36928 r8192 d24512 u69632 alloc=17*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 1011008
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 cma=64M cma=256M  smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:36:A1:DA vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=6c586e13-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 3735564K/4050944K available (8192K kernel code, 687K rwdata, 2408K rodata, 2048K init, 850K bss, 53236K reserved, 262144K cma-reserved, 3264512K highmem)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
                   vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
                   fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
                   vmalloc : 0xf0800000 - 0xff800000   ( 240 MB)
                   lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xf0000000   ( 768 MB)
                   pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
                   modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
                     .text : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   (10208 kB)
                     .init : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   (2048 kB)
                     .data : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   ( 688 kB)
                      .bss : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   ( 851 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 28692 entries in 85 pages
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] GIC: Using split EOI/Deactivate mode
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 54.00MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0xc743ce346, max_idle_ns: 440795203123 ns
[    0.000005] sched_clock: 56 bits at 54MHz, resolution 18ns, wraps every 4398046511102ns
[    0.000021] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 18ns
[    0.000248] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000704] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.000763] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 108.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=540000)
[    0.000799] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001082] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001115] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001893] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.002313] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.002971] Setting up static identity map for 0x200000 - 0x20003c
[    0.003146] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.004026] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.004846] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.005787] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.006683] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.006818] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.006886] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (432.00 BogoMIPS).
[    0.006909] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.006929] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.007730] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.017885] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 40 variant 8 rev 0
[    0.018118] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.018160] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.025675] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.026544] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.029463] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.030905] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.030936] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.031140] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.034221] bcm2835-mbox fe00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.050028] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2020-02-12 12:36, variant start
[    0.060043] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is c3c8dbdf147686fb0c3f32aece709d0653368810
[    0.102895] bcm2835-dma fe007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at (ptrval), dmachans=0x1
[    0.106027] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.106400] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.106609] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.106682] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.106765] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.107949] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.186484] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.186587] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.186746] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.186945] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.187472] simple-framebuffer: probe of 0.framebuffer failed with error -12
[    0.196798] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.197466] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes)
[    0.197513] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.197594] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.197679] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.197817] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.197862] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.198136] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.198698] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.198724] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.198745] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.198767] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.198795] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.201780] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    0.201974] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=20 bucket_order=6
[    0.211001] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.211525] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.211563] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.211585] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.211616] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    0.213876] Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.213901] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.214022] bounce: pool size: 64 pages
[    0.214075] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 250)
[    0.214261] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.214285] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.214449] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.214472] io scheduler mq-deadline registered (default)
[    0.214495] io scheduler kyber registered
[    0.246380] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: dmabounce: initialised - 32768 kB, threshold 0x00000000c0000000
[    0.246425] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: could not get clock
[    0.246500] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: host bridge /scb/pcie@7d500000 ranges:
[    0.246553] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   MEM 0x600000000..0x603ffffff -> 0xf8000000
[    0.297982] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: link up, 5.0 Gbps x1 (!SSC)
[    0.298283] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.298314] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-01]
[    0.298344] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x600000000-0x603ffffff] (bus address [0xf8000000-0xfbffffff])
[    0.298408] pci 0000:00:00.0: [14e4:2711] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.298547] pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    0.301279] PCI: bus0: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    0.301311] pci 0000:00:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring
[    0.301540] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1106:3483] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    0.301665] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    0.301982] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3cold
[    0.304726] PCI: bus1: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    0.304757] pci_bus 0000:01: busn_res: [bus 01] end is updated to 01
[    0.304804] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    0.304838] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x600000fff 64bit]
[    0.304926] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    0.304955] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    0.305178] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0142)
[    0.305367] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: Signaling PME with IRQ 53
[    0.305538] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: AER enabled with IRQ 53
[    0.305720] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0142)
[    0.308308] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.310176] iproc-rng200 fe104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    0.310406] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    0.310918] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    0.311321] gpiomem-bcm2835 fe200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0xfe200000
[    0.321531] brd: module loaded
[    0.331143] loop: module loaded
[    0.331908] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    0.333595] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    0.334016] bcmgenet fd580000.genet: failed to get enet clock
[    0.334047] bcmgenet fd580000.genet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
[    0.334078] bcmgenet fd580000.genet: failed to get enet-wol clock
[    0.334107] bcmgenet fd580000.genet: failed to get enet-eee clock
[    0.334143] bcmgenet: Skipping UMAC reset
[    0.334387] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: DMA mask not set
[    0.347981] libphy: bcmgenet MII bus: probed
[    0.388486] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus at 0x(ptrval)
[    0.389413] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    0.389489] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    0.389564] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    0.389877] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.389923] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.392165] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000001000000890
[    0.392502] genirq: irq_chip Brcm_MSI did not update eff. affinity mask of irq 54
[    0.393379] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 4.19
[    0.393414] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.393443] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.393467] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.19.97-v7l+ xhci-hcd
[    0.393491] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    0.394030] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.394123] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.394611] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.394647] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.394689] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    0.395111] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 4.19
[    0.395143] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.395171] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.395194] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.19.97-v7l+ xhci-hcd
[    0.395218] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    0.395723] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.395787] hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    0.396969] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    0.397173] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    0.397182] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    0.397191] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    0.397203] Module dwc_common_port init
[    0.397405] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    0.397527] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.397707] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.398915] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    0.400364] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.400389] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.400773] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    0.403394] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    0.403557] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    0.403705] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.403728] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    0.404509] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = (ptrval), is_master = 0
[    0.406296] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    0.415186] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    0.416364] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    0.416406] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.416503] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.416771] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    0.417389] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.417420] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    0.424365] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    0.424445] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 34, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.555238] console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    1.564071] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    1.571858] brcmstb_thermal fd5d2200.thermal: registered AVS TMON of-sensor driver
[    1.580056] sdhci-iproc fe340000.emmc2: Linked as a consumer to regulator.3
[    1.587108] sdhci-iproc fe340000.emmc2: Linked as a consumer to regulator.4
[    1.625981] mmc0: SDHCI controller on fe340000.emmc2 [fe340000.emmc2] using ADMA
[    1.635768] of_cfs_init
[    1.638421] of_cfs_init: OK
[    1.641858] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=6c586e13-02...
[    1.732647] mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDHC card at address aaaa
[    1.740366] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SC16G 14.8 GiB
[    1.750026]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    1.770101] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.778290] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    1.792978] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.803619] Freeing unused kernel memory: 2048K
[    1.808422] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    1.817993] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.882572] random: fast init done
[    2.000577] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
[    2.008834] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.015986] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    2.021698] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.025724] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    2.266596] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    2.360982] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.366647] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    2.377991] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.415173] systemd[1]: systemd 241 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    2.437246] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    2.453947] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <th-10-01-apl-02>.
[    2.524883] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2813, bcdDevice=90.11
[    2.533360] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.540755] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    2.544879] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[    2.559792] hub 1-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.564019] hub 1-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    2.624733] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[    2.947996] usb 1-1.3.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    3.092737] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.099964] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[    3.107244] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.108559] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.115590] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    3.122680] usb 1-1.3.1: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    3.122690] usb 1-1.3.1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    3.153230] usb-storage 1-1.3.1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    3.160640] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.3.1:1.2
[    3.166576] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Journal Audit Socket being skipped.
[    3.174730] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.181441] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    3.187038] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    3.197397] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    3.213250] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    3.223715] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    3.278024] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    3.438639] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[    3.447262] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.447273] usb 1-1.3.2: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    3.447283] usb 1-1.3.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    3.491992] usb-storage 1-1.3.2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    3.503911] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.3.2:1.2
[    3.658049] usb 1-1.3.3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    3.804883] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2813, bcdDevice=90.11
[    3.804900] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.804914] usb 1-1.3.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    3.804926] usb 1-1.3.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[    3.807299] hub 1-1.3.3:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.808073] hub 1-1.3.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    3.828750] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    3.938004] usb 1-1.3.4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    3.951474] systemd-journald[109]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    4.084813] usb 1-1.3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2813, bcdDevice=90.11
[    4.084829] usb 1-1.3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.084843] usb 1-1.3.4: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    4.084855] usb 1-1.3.4: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[    4.087046] hub 1-1.3.4:1.0: USB hub found
[    4.087805] hub 1-1.3.4:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    4.179369] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[    4.180641] sd 0:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    4.188053] usb 1-1.3.3.1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[    4.229192] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    4.330841] usb 1-1.3.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[    4.330871] usb 1-1.3.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.330887] usb 1-1.3.3.1: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    4.330908] usb 1-1.3.3.1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    4.349324] usb-storage 1-1.3.3.1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    4.351583] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1.3.3.1:1.2
[    4.439272] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    4.448060] usb 1-1.3.4.1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[    4.467262] rndis_host 1-1.3.1:1.0 eth1: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3.1, RNDIS device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
[    4.469701] rndis_host 1-1.3.2:1.0 eth2: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3.2, RNDIS device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
[    4.472631] rndis_host 1-1.3.3.1:1.0 eth3: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3.3.1, RNDIS device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
[    4.472822] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[    4.569015] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[    4.570039] sd 1:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    4.577510] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.584156] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    4.589388] usb 1-1.3.4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[    4.589405] usb 1-1.3.4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.589419] usb 1-1.3.4.1: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    4.589431] usb 1-1.3.4.1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    4.626747] bcm2835_audio soc:audio: card created with 8 channels
[    4.629035] rndis_host 1-1.3.4.1:1.0 eth4: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3.4.1, RNDIS device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
[    4.630685] usb-storage 1-1.3.4.1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    4.642233] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-1.3.4.1:1.2
[    4.653900] [drm] Initialized v3d 1.0.0 20180419 for fec00000.v3d on minor 0
[    4.698051] usb 1-1.3.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[    4.820105] rpivid-mem feb00000.hevc-decoder: rpivid-hevcmem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb00000 length 0x0000ffff
[    4.822703] rpivid-mem feb10000.rpivid-local-intc: rpivid-intcmem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb10000 length 0x00000fff
[    4.826773] rpivid-mem feb20000.h264-decoder: rpivid-h264mem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb20000 length 0x0000ffff
[    4.828346] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    4.830767] rpivid-mem feb30000.vp9-decoder: rpivid-vp9mem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb30000 length 0x0000ffff
[    4.839733] usb 1-1.3.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[    4.839751] usb 1-1.3.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.839764] usb 1-1.3.3.2: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    4.839777] usb 1-1.3.3.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    4.857916] rndis_host 1-1.3.3.2:1.0 eth5: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3.3.2, RNDIS device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
[    4.859222] usb-storage 1-1.3.3.2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    4.869050] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1.3.3.2:1.2
[    4.869328] vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.871477] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    4.881365] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[    4.881388] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    4.883846] [drm] No displays found. Consider forcing hotplug if HDMI is attached
[    4.883949] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound fe600000.firmwarekms (ops vc4_fkms_ops [vc4])
[    4.885678] [vc_sm_connected_init]: installed successfully
[    4.886162] [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for soc:gpu on minor 1
[    4.886174] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    4.886184] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    4.886193] [drm] Setting vblank_disable_immediate to false because get_vblank_timestamp == NULL
[    4.898275] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.898957] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.920335] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.921901] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.934173] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[    4.934208] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[    4.944133] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[    4.944165] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[    4.948024] usb 1-1.3.4.2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[    4.952006] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[    4.952046] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
[    5.089879] usb 1-1.3.4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[    5.089896] usb 1-1.3.4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.089910] usb 1-1.3.4.2: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    5.089922] usb 1-1.3.4.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    5.109436] rndis_host 1-1.3.4.2:1.0 eth6: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3.4.2, RNDIS device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
[    5.110697] usb-storage 1-1.3.4.2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    5.123060] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1.3.4.2:1.2
[    5.185028] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    5.185233] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    5.198050] usb 1-1.3.3.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[    5.343398] usb 1-1.3.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[    5.343416] usb 1-1.3.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.343429] usb 1-1.3.3.3: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    5.343442] usb 1-1.3.3.3: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    5.354856] rndis_host 1-1.3.3.3:1.0 eth7: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3.3.3, RNDIS device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
[    5.355889] usb-storage 1-1.3.3.3:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    5.362019] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.3.3.3:1.2
[    5.380973] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[    5.382786] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    5.383213] sd 2:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    5.391133] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    5.448018] usb 1-1.3.4.3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[    5.589784] usb 1-1.3.4.3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[    5.589801] usb 1-1.3.4.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.589814] usb 1-1.3.4.3: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE ```


  [1]: https://dropmefiles.com/cWJL6
````

Comment: Sounds like lack of power. 10 modems will need 5-10 Amps (maybe more), is your hub able to provide such a current?

Comment: We have a 30W power supply together with a hub. But how much ampere is there?

Comment: 30/5 = 6 Amps...

Comment: For your question in the title: see my answer at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109455/error-when-connecting-more-than-ten-usb-devices-on-raspberry-pi-4/

Comment: The conclusion there, that cable,  hub or power issues are the most likely candidates applies here as well.